# Not able to convert normal C# class to MVC model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

C# class -

```
namespace BAL
{
    public class TargetMasterBAL
    {
        public Int32 TargetMasterID { get; set; }
        public Double TargetAmount { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

C# class Inherited in MVC Models-

```
using BAL;

namespace MVCWeb.Models
{
    public class TargetMaster : TargetMasterBAL
    {
    }
}
```

.cshtml page -

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCWeb.Models.TargetMaster>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "HomeScreen";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
```

controller code -

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCWeb.Models;

namespace MVCWeb.Controllers.Target
{
    public class TargetMasterController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult HomeScreen()
        {
            try
            {
                List<TargetMaster> lstTargetMasters1 = new List<TargetMaster>();

                var s = DAL.TargetMasterDAL.getTargetMasters(null, null, null, 1, 1000, false);

                return View(s);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BAL.TargetMasterBAL]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVCWeb.Models.TargetMaster]'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BAL.TargetMasterBAL]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVCWeb.Models.TargetMaster]'.

Comment: And what is wrong with your flow? I mean, you pass parent class to child reference. In C# it is impossible. You need to inherit your TargetMasterBal from TargetMaster or cast to TargetMaster your TargetMasterBal list and then your code will work properly.

Comment: TargetMasterBAL is my parent class which is inherited by TargetMaster class

Comment: yes, you are right. And you pass TargetMasterBAL into model that expect TargetMaster. You can't pass parent type to child type variable.

Comment: kindly help me with the solution

Comment: ok. Change your model type to **model IEnumerable<MVCWeb.Models.TargetMasterBAL>** in your view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the returned items to the desired type.

```
//...

List<TargetMaster> lstTargetMasters1 = s.Select(_ => new TargetMaster {
        TargetMasterID = _.TargetMasterID,
        //...other properties
    })
    .ToList();
return View(lstTargetMasters1);

//...
```

Comment: hmm... what is this `_` practice.  That is really unnerving to see.

Comment: i already tried by using below thing but in this i need to map the each and every property manually. is there any way to do it automatically.

Comment: List<TargetMaster> lstTargetMasters1 = new List<TargetMaster>();

                foreach (BAL.TargetMasterBAL item in lstTargetMasters)
                {
                    TargetMaster TM = new TargetMaster();
                    TM.TargetMasterID = item.TargetMasterID;
                    TM.TargetAmount = item.TargetAmount;
                    TM.ValidFrom = item.ValidFrom;
                    TM.ValidTo = item.ValidTo;
                

                    lstTargetMasters1.Add(TM);
                }

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you can't put `parent object` to a `child reference variable` implicitly. See your exception details.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BAL.TargetMasterBAL]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVCWeb.Models.TargetMaster]'.

So to solve this, Change your method parameter to `IEnumerable<TargetMasterBAL>`

**Alternatively**,

Cast your list to `TargetMaster` list as below

`List<TargetMaster> list = (List<TargetMaster>) new List<TargetMasterBAL>;`

And why are you creating the extra `TargetMaster` class inheriting from `TargetMasterBAL` if you are not adding properties to `TargetMaster` class?

Comment: I think he just hide properties from TargetMaster from us. Maybe it is unnecessary in question. Plus that, he didn't show at least signature of getTargetMasters method.

Comment: No `TargetMaster` is necessary as the error is related to casting. And yes, `getTargetMasters` method body is necessary to know exactly what the error is, but I somehow figured it out from the `Exception` he posted.

Comment: i have namespace BAL  i.e. in different project and i want to use the same class in mvc project without defining the properties of it in the mvc model class, kindly help with how i can use the same and resolve the above error

Comment: Just include the name of your `namespace`(BAL) wherever you want to use your `class` defined under particular `namespace` like `Using MyProject.BAL` and BOOM you can use classes defined under different `nampespaces`

Comment: so how can i defined the model class for the same BAL class in mvc,because i need to do crud operations on it

Comment: Just add your model `class` wherever you want and you can use that `class` by including the namespace for that class in **same project**. To use that `class` in the different project you have to add a reference to the project under which your `class` is defined and then you can add the namespace to use your class

Comment: using BAL;

namespace MVCWeb.Models
{
    public class TargetMaster : TargetMasterBAL
    {
    }
} by this way i can inherit the bal class to the model class but if i do this then it throws me the same error shown above